# How do I explicitly specify an out-of-tree source in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I looked at this post: [Using CMake to statically link to a library outside of the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569548/using-cmake-to-statically-link-to-a-library-outside-of-the-project).  But I'm still having trouble interpreting what this means:

```
add_subdirectory(/path/to/the/library/source/directory subproject/grzeslib)
```

I'm assuming "/path/to/the/library/source/directory" means the path from the hard drive, but I don't understand what "subproject/grzeslib" means.
Now I tried:

```
include_directories(../path/to/dir)
add_subdirectory (../path/to/dir .)
```

But I'm getting an elaborate warning.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The second parameter is output directory for the results of the targets from that subdirectory.

From the documentation here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_subdirectory.html

> **add_subdirectory**
>
> Add a subdirectory to the build.
>
> ```
> add_subdirectory(source_dir [binary_dir]
>              [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL])
> ```
>
> Add a subdirectory to the build.
>
> - The source_dir specifies the directory in which the source CMakeLists.txt and code files are located. If it is a relative path it
>     will be evaluated with respect to the current directory (the typical
>     usage), but it may also be an absolute path.
> - The binary_dir specifies the directory in which to place the output files. If it is a relative path it will be evaluated with respect to
>     the current output directory, but it may also be an absolute path. If
>     binary_dir is not specified, the value of source_dir, before expanding
>     any relative path, will be used (the typical usage).
> - The CMakeLists.txt file in the specified source directory will be    processed immediately by CMake before processing in the current input 
>     file continues beyond this command.
> - If the EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL argument is provided then targets in the subdirectory will not be included in the ALL target of the parent
>     directory by default, and will be excluded from IDE project files.
>     Users must explicitly build targets in the subdirectory. This is meant
>     for use when the subdirectory contains a separate part of the project
>     that is useful but not necessary, such as a set of examples. Typically
>     the subdirectory should contain its own project() command invocation
>     so that a full build system will be generated in the subdirectory
>     (such as a VS IDE solution file). Note that inter-target dependencies
>     supercede this exclusion. If a target built by the parent project
>     depends on a target in the subdirectory, the dependee target will be
>     included in the parent project build system to satisfy the dependency.

Comment: Okay thanks, but I'm not quite sure how to decide on where to put the output files.

Comment: So if I use "add_subdirectory (../path/to/dir .) " why aren't binary files added to the current directory?  Should the binary_dir be the build folder?

Comment: I made binary_dir my build folder and that got rid of the warning.

Comment: it didn't solve error I received "add_subdirectory not given a binary directory but the given source directory" , first answer at "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408169/cmake-error-add-subdirectory-not-given-a-binary-directory" solved the problem, be adding 'build' to the command

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html)

> Add a subdirectory to the build. The source_dir specifies the
>   directory in which the source CMakeLists.txt and code files are
>   located. If it is a relative path it will be evaluated with respect to
>   the current directory (the typical usage), but it may also be an
>   absolute path. The binary_dir specifies the directory in which to
>   place the output files. If it is a relative path it will be evaluated
>   with respect to the current output directory, but it may also be an
>   absolute path. If binary_dir is not specified, the value of
>   source_dir, before expanding any relative path, will be used (the
>   typical usage). The CMakeLists.txt file in the specified source
>   directory will be processed immediately by CMake before processing in
>   the current input file continues beyond this command

From your example, all the binaries created in "/path/to/the/library/source/directory" will be placed in "subproject/grzeslib", it's a good thing to keep "clean" the source dirs.

Comment: I'm getting a warning from CMake that the above code I added isn't a good idea.  Where should I put the output files?

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15570165/2482283

need specifiy second parameter binary path, it is relative to ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}

```
add_subdirectory(/path/to/the/library/source/directory subproject/grzeslib)
```