# CMake Error: "add_subdirectory not given a binary directory"

Tags: c++, build, cmake, googletest

I am trying to integrate Google Test into the subproject of bigger project and I cannot find the solution that would be satisfying for me.

I have two constraints:

- the source code of Google Test is already somewhere in the project structure (thus using URL to download it from git repository is not an option)
- the source code of Google Test is not a subdirectory of my subproject (and never will)

So when I tried to do something like this:

```
add_subdirectory( ${GOOGLETEST_PROJECT_LOCATION})
```

I received:

```
CMake Error at unit_tests/CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory not given a binary directory but the given source
  directory "${GOOGLETEST_PROJECT_LOCATION}" is not a subdirectory of
  "${UNIT_TEST_DIRECTORY}".  When
  specifying an out-of-tree source a binary directory must be explicitly
  specified.
```

On the other hand maybe `ExternalProject_Add` could be a solution but I do not know how shall I use it when I do not want to download sources at all and use sources from specific location in the project.

Project structure looks more or like like this:

```
3rdparty 
    |--googletest 
...
subproject
   |--module1
      |--file1.cpp
      |--CMakeLists.txt
   |--module2
      |--file2.cpp
      |--CMakeLists.txt
   |--include
      |--module1
          |--file1.h
      |--module2
          |--file2.h
   |--unit_test
       |--module1
           |--file1test.cpp
       |--module2
           |--file2test.cpp
       |--CMakeLists.txt
   |--CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The error message is clear - you should also specify **build directory** for googletest.

```
# This will build googletest under build/ subdirectory in the project's build tree
add_subdirectory( ${GOOGLETEST_PROJECT_LOCATION} build)
```

When you give *relative* path (as a *source* directory) to `add_subdirectory` call, CMake automatically uses the same relative path for the *build* directory.

But in case of *absolute source* path (and when this path isn't in your source tree), CMake cannot guess *build* directory, and you need to provide it **explicitly**:

See also [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_subdirectory.html) for `add_subdirectory` command.

Comment: Is `../Lib1` considered absolute to CMake? since having this kind of relative path gives this error as well. I thought its ok with relative path not to include a bin dir!

Comment: In my answer post there is another condition for the source path - "when this path isn't in your source tree" - when CMake requires explicit specification of the build directory. That is, if you call ``add_subdirectory(../Lib1)`` from the **top** `CMakeLists.txt`, CMake will emit error about "not given a binary directory". Note also, using a build directory outside of the top-level build directory is something which should be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

I feel obligated to comment on this because this was the top search result when I was googling this error.

For me, I'm apparently an idiot: I had modified the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the `src` directory of my project, but I didn't realize the file was locked and VS Code wasn't actually saving even when I hit Ctrl+S. Check the file tab in VS Code and see if there's a white dot there, indicating the file isn't saved. Hit Ctrl+S and see if you get a pop-up in the lower-right corner prompting you to try again as superuser.

I've still got errors, but they're new errors that make sense for my project.