# How to properly write CMakeLists for library outside project folder

Tags: c++, cmake

I decided to try CMake for my new project. I've spent some hours reading the official documentation and tutorials so I've gained some basic knowledge, but unable to write proper CMakeLists for my project.

The file hierarchy looks like this:

```
project
|-- library
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- lib.cpp
|   `-- lib.h
|-- app1
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- app1.cpp
|   |-- app1.h
|   `-- main.cpp
|-- app2
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- app2.cpp
|   |-- app2.h
|   `-- main.cpp
`-- app3
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- app3.cpp
    |-- app3.h
    `-- main.cpp
```

The point is that I want to compile the library as a static library so it can be used by app1, app2, app3 and so on. The reason for this structure is that each appN has it's own main function that will be run on AWS Lambda, but I'd like to write some common code shared between them in the library.

From what I've read so far it's easy to add a library if it was in a sub-directory of the appN using `add_directory()` and add it to the `target_link_libraries()`, but I cannot figure out how to add a library that is outside of the appN folders. I tried using relative paths like `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../library/lib.a` etc, but then CMake gives error that library is outside project folder.

I'm sure there is some way to do this. I've read some about CMake modules and `find_package()`, but it seems to be a bit overkill/complicated for this use-case, I think?

Comment: "..., but then CMake gives error that library is outside project folder." - You have checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408169/cmake-error-add-subdirectory-not-given-a-binary-directory) with the similar error message, haven't you?

Comment: or you can use a master cmakelists for all the projects that use your lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a main CMakeLists.txt that includes the subdirectories which again has their CMakeLists.txt. I found this approach to be the cleanest.

If someone else come by this I've included my complete CMakeLists.txt files below for reference along with the updated file hierarchy.

**File hierarchy**

```
project
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- library
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- lib.cpp
|   `-- lib.h
|-- app1
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- app1.cpp
|   |-- app1.h
|   `-- main.cpp
|-- app2
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- app2.cpp
|   |-- app2.h
|   `-- main.cpp
`-- app3
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- app3.cpp
    |-- app3.h
    `-- main.cpp
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(MyProject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_subdirectory(library)
add_subdirectory(app1)
add_subdirectory(app2)
add_subdirectory(app3)
```

**library/CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(library)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC lib.cpp lib.h)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

**app1/CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(app1)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp app1.cpp app1.h)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} library)
```

**app2/CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(app2)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp app2.cpp app2.h)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} library)
```

**app3/CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(app3)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp app3.cpp app3.h)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} library)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this work in a main CMakeLists.txt (where you create the PROJECT)?

```
ADD_LIBRARY(MyLib STATIC library/lib.cpp library/lib.h)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(app1 STATIC app1/app1.cpp app1/app1.h)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(app2 STATIC app2/app2.cpp app2/app2.h)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(app3 STATIC app3/app3.cpp app3/app3.h)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(app1 MyLib)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(app2 MyLib)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(app3 MyLib)
```

Comment: Starting out with a main CMakeLists.txt file as you stated here really helped me a lot and later led me to create CmakeLists.txt files and so on as I have described in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @iQt Great! You should make your response as an Answer, so future people can find how you solved your problem and your question is marked as solved.