# Eclipse CMake support both global project and subprojects

Tags: c++, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I have a project that I'm trying to configure to make use of CMake, and to make my life easier I'm organizing it as a series of libraries that I'm treating as subprojects.

```
MyProject
|-- common-cmake
|   |-- common-functions1.cmake
|   |-- common-functions2.cmake
|   `-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- lib1
|   |-- include
|   |   `-- someClass.h
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- someClass.cpp
|   |-- test
|   |   |-- include
|   |   |   `-- someClassTest.h
|   |   |-- src
|   |   |   `-- someClassTest.cpp
|   |   `-- CMakeLists.txt
|   `-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- lib2
|   `-- <snip>
|-- lib3
|   `-- <snip>
`-- CMakeLists.txt
```

There's a global CMakeLists.txt in MyProject that handles the cross-library specifics (such as version information and installation directories) and ensures that everything is included via

```
add_subdirectory(cmake-common)
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)
add_subdirectory(lib3)
```

common-cmake contains common logic to avoid repetition in each library's or test's CMakeLists.txt (such as common shared library definition since all of the libraries have a common structure). Each library contains a CMakeLists.txt with the necessary information so that it itself can be compiled, and includes its test directory. Each test in turn has its own CMakeLists.txt to provide the necessary details for the compilation of the tests for the library it is contained within. Thus, both the library and its test CMakeLists.txt is dependent on details the global CMakeLists.txt provides and functions that are contained within the common-cmake.

After fighting with the specifics of this, I've got it working. I can kick-off a build from the global level and build/test/install all libraries as well as for an individual library via the appropriate make target.

Now that I've got this working at the global level, I'm trying to get this working in Eclipse. I've managed to get the global project imported and working by calling

```
cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
```

at the global level, however this means that *everything* is contained within a single Eclipse project and I find it extremely unwieldy to work with. Ideally I'd like to have each of the libraries as its own project within Eclipse. I can import the library as a project from within Eclipse directly, but when I do that Eclipse in turn starts throwing errors relating to failure to CMakeCache.txt not existing, or the common functions from common-cmake not being available (since it's not longer starting from the global CMakeLists.txt, those common files are never added).

The only way around this that I can think of would be to allow each library to be both part of the global project (as it is right now) as well as to be usable independently. I've been trying to figure out how this could be done, but unfortunately I haven't had any success.

```
add_subdirectory("..")
add_subdirectory("../common-cmake")
```

add_subdirectory doesn't allow me to add anything that's outside of the current directory's subdirectories (which makes a lot of sense), and the only way I've found is to include each file individually and have a rather ugly flag in place to prevent duplication, where the global and the project check each other's flag to prevent stepping on each other's toes.

```
# Global CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(cmake-common)

if(NOT DEFINED ${PROJECT_BUILD})
    set(FULL_BUILD true)
    add_subdirectory(lib1)
    add_subdirectory(lib2)
    add_subdirectory(lib3)
endif()


# lib CMakeLists.txt
if(NOT DEFINED ${FULL_BUILD})
    set(PROJECT_BUILD true)
    include("../common-cmake/common-functions1.cmake")
    include("../common-cmake/common-functions2.cmake")
endif()
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? Is what I'm trying to do antithetical to CMake and thus not possible? Is there a better way to achieve my end goal?

Comment: "add_subdirectory doesn't allow me to add anything that's outside of the current directory's subdirectories ..." - No, there is no such constraint for `add_subdirectory`. If you want to handle the error `add_subdirectory not given a binary directory but the given source directory "..." is not a subdirectory of  "..."`, then see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50408169/3440745).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! that looks to have done the trick!